# Requesting the self-written Identity Service

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0

I have my own identity server, implementing oauh2
it can create access and refresh tokens, and has /token endpoint, which can return this tokens
let's say http://authserver/
also, i have a web application to this service, which is a simple page with two fields and login button
(let's say it can be accessed via http://web.front
I have an api, which can use tokens issued by my IS
let's say http://some/api
What should I do, to allow 3-rd application/site to use my IS as external authorization provider.

The required flow: User is opening http://somesite.com in browser
press link, and see http://web.front
enters his credentials there, and using the token requested from http://authserver, http://somesite.com requests information from http://some/api

I'm feeling that I am missing some little, but crucial thing here, but can't figure it out.

just to mention - .net (not core), react.js

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by using IdentityService4